# How to log exceptions of a Custom Exception Filter(implements IExceptionFilter) to a file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webapi

```
public class CustomExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute,IExceptionFilter
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var writer = File.CreateText(filepath);

        if (context.Exception is UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            writer.Write(context.Exception.Message);
           
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            writer.Write(context.Exception.Message);
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The .txt file I specified stays empty

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to close it afterwards, flushing any buffer to disk:

```
public class CustomExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute,IExceptionFilter
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        // Wrapped in using so it's disposed of
        using (var writer = File.CreateText(filepath)) 
        {
            if (context.Exception is UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(context.Exception.Message);
               
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                context.ExceptionHandled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                writer.WriteLine(context.Exception.Message);

                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                context.ExceptionHandled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also switched to `WriteLine()` so it adds `\r\n` automatically for you.

However, the problem here is this could be invoked by multiple requests concurrently leading to issues.

What you should do is use an existing logging framework and log through that, that should cater for writing out to log files etc.

Options include [Serilog](https://serilog.net/), [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/) and plenty of others.

If you want to roll your own I'd probably go with a shared concurrent queue and background service that processes the queue to disk.